# Best way to output teffects results from Stata to Excel?

Tags: regression, stata, export-to-excel

I want to output the ATE, std error, and p-value from this code:

```
teffects aipw (dep_var, logit) (treatment pred1 pred2 pred3)
```

I used this code:

```
putexcel set "$root/filename.xlsx", sheet("5") modify
putexcel A1=`e(stat)'
```

but it says "ate not found." Shouldn't the ate be stored automatically in e(stat)?

Answer (score 2):

`e(stat)` stores the statistic that is estimated as a string, i.e. "ate" or "pomeans". This doesn't contain the actual point estimate.

The coefficients and standard errors can be accessed after any estimation command with the following syntax: `_b[coef]`, `_se[coef]` or `[eqno]_b[coef]`/`_b[eqno:coef]` and `[eqno]_se[coef]`/`_se[eqno:coef]` in the case of multiple equation models.

You can specify the `coeflegend` option to most estimation commands to see how coefficients are named.

Example:

```
. webuse cattaneo2
(Excerpt from Cattaneo (2010) Journal of Econometrics 155: 138-154)

. teffects aipw (bweight prenatal1 mmarried mage fbaby) (mbsmoke mmarried c.mage##c.mage fbaby medu, probit), coeflegend

Iteration 0:   EE criterion =  4.629e-21  
Iteration 1:   EE criterion =  1.939e-25  

Treatment-effects estimation                    Number of obs     =      4,642
Estimator      : augmented IPW
Outcome model  : linear by ML
Treatment model: probit
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               bweight |      Coef.  Legend
-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
ATE                    |
               mbsmoke |
(smoker vs nonsmoker)  |  -230.9892  _b[ATE:r1vs0.mbsmoke]
-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
POmean                 |
               mbsmoke |
            nonsmoker  |   3403.355  _b[POmean:0.mbsmoke]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. di _b[ATE:r1vs0.mbsmoke]
-230.9892

. di _se[ATE:r1vs0.mbsmoke]
26.210565
```

Any other statistics can be obtained from r(table), type `matrix list r(table)` after the estimation command to see this. For example, to obtain the pvalue:

```
mat A = r(table)
scalar pval = A[4,1]
di pval
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to access/store the ATE and standard error. Do you know how to access the p val?